# Are webMathematica functions totally different compared with Mathematica?

Tags: webmathematica

Recently, I configured `WebMathematica` in my system. I tested with inbuilt examples, all are working fine.

Basically, `Helloworld` program returns `Date[]` output. I tried with `Dynamic` wrapper around `Date[]`, the corresponding code is below.

```
 <msp:evaluate>
  Dynamic[Date[]]
 </msp:evaluate>
```

I restarted server, it's not working. It shows `Dynamic[Date[]]` as output. In the same way I tried `Button`instead of `Date`, the corresponding code is below, it's also not working, it returns *Mathematica* code.

```
 <msp:evaluate>
  Button[Style["Click", Black, Bold,25], (MessageDialog["This is Tested by Grandhi..."]), ImageSize -> {180, 60}, Background -> LightGray]
 </msp:evaluate>
```

I have 3 questions.

1.How can I fix this problem ?

2.where can I get good WebMathematica examples?

3.Do all *Mathematica* functions work in `WebMathematica`?

Comment: Useful answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21601/what-can-webmathematica-do-that-cdf-cannot-do): "The UI part of a webMathematica application can't be programmed in Mathematica but must be HTML"

Comment: @cormullion how `<msp:evaluate>` will work,is it `WebMathematica` tag or `Html` tag.
If we create `GUI` elements through `HTML` or any scripting language.how can `Mathematica` code interacted with that..for that I seen inbuilt examples code,I didn't understood anything.I understood up to,calling one html page to another page.after that I didn't understood anything.

Comment: I know less than you about webMathematica... I suggest you contact Wolfram Support to find out about training courses or post-sales support. Did your organization research the requirements before buying it?

Comment: @cormullion earlier,we developed windows applications using `Mathematica`. After that we thought to develop web based Apps for that we are using Premier Service. I think it's free of charge.

Comment: webMathematica is based on a very common technology called java server pages (JSP). `msp` is, I think, a shortcut for mathematica server pages and formally used as an xml namespace in that tag. If you interested what this all means and how it is used you definitely should read some documentation. As powerful as webMathematica is: you need to learn some technology before you can do stuff thats more advanced than what the examples provide. If the docs that come with webMathematica don't cover your needs you might find more information when searching for documentation about JSP and XML/XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

No. But `Dynamic` and `Button` and so on just are not and cannot be supported.
However, you can programmmatically generate CDF files, and put them onto your server. And in CDF's, when run through the CDF-plugin (on a Windows or OSX client; no Linux yet unfortunately) you can have `Button` etc.

Comment: you mean,without setting CDF-plugin,we shouldn't create `GUI` elements through `WebMathematica`.is it right?
how can I set CDF-plugin. Is there any tutorials for this?